# NP.max function error in Python 3

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I am learning Background removal with OpenCV code from 
http://www.codepasta.com/site/vision/segmentation/

The error is from np.max

```
edgeImg = np.max( np.array([ edgedetect(blurred[:,:, 0]), edgedetect(blurred[:,:, 1]), edgedetect(blurred[:,:, 2]) ]), axis=0 )
```

When I change from np.max into np.maximum the error as follow:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "deteksipinggir-sobel.py", line 77, in <module>
segment('078.jpg')
File "deteksipinggir-sobel.py", line 49, in segment
np.array([edgedetect(blurred[:, :, 0]), edgedetect(blurred[:, :, 1]), edgedetect(blurred[:, :, 2])]), axis=0)
ValueError: invalid number of arguments
```

When I change from np.max into np.amax the error as follow:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "deteksipinggir-sobel.py", line 77, in <module>
segment('078.jpg')
File "deteksipinggir-sobel.py", line 49, in segment
np.array([edgedetect(blurred[:, :, 0]), edgedetect(blurred[:, :, 1]), edgedetect(blurred[:, :, 2])]), axis=0)
File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 2272, in amax
out=out, **kwargs)
File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py", line 26, in _amax
return umr_maximum(a, axis, None, out, keepdims)
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
```

I am using python 3, please help, thanks.

Comment: The edgedetect routine on the website you point us to has a fundamental problem: no return statement. Could you please confirm that you used this code because if you did your problem is identified.

Comment: `np.max(a,b,c) => np.max((a,b,c))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the numpy documentation [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html): `numpy.maximum` expects two input arrays as arguments:

```
numpy.maximum(arr1, arr2)
```

Whereas `numpy.max` only requires one input array as an argument:

```
numpy.max(arr1)
```

Make sure you are providing `numpy.maximum` at least two arrays as arguments.